# htaccess: first rewriterule works, second not

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here's my code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rwp=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?act=$1
```

Problem: works first RewriteRule only. Second RewriteRule doesn't work. If I write that RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?act=$1 first, then it works, but RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rwp=$1 does not.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Suppose that you're vising the page: `some_file_which_isn't_there`. Where would it redirect to?

Comment: second rule get index.php that not satisfy as it's an existent file.

Answer (score 0):

You first rules is telling it to redirect to `index.php?rwp=` if the file or document doesn't exist, and the second one does the same but to redirect it to `index.php?act=` Your first rule will always catch it so your second rule will never run. What you'll have to do is something like this in the index.php file:

In your index.php file you will be using the variable in the `rwp` parameter to decide what to show. Have a fallback option there to show the information that would be shown from the `act` parameter (either with an else statement or refresh the page with the variable on the `act` parameter).